# Remove HTML Table Tag IF Contain Something

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 tables, some of them has a child items such as: `<tr><td>...` and others has nothing just a table tag without anything inside. i want to remove empty tables.
**note**: all tables has a `tbldetails` name.

```
var lengthtbldetail = document.getElementsByName('tbldetails');

for(var itd=0;itd<lengthtbldetail.length;itd++){
var tbdtlv = 0;

if(lengthtbldetail[itd].innerHTML.indexOf('<td>') != -1) {

// REMOVE IT...

}
}
```

**Here** an example to solve:

```html
<table name="tbldetails">
<tr>
<td>
Table 1
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />

<!--I want to Remove the following tables:-->
<table name="tbldetails">
</table>
<table name="tbldetails">
</table>
<table name="tbldetails">
</table>
<br />

<table name="tbldetails">
<tr>
<td>
Table 3
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it work for one table, in my case, i have 3 to 20 table which has an empty row and td

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild). Your **if** block needs to be

```
if(lengthtbldetail[itd].innerHTML.indexOf('<td>') == -1) 
{
   lengthtbldetail[itd].parentNode.removeChild( lengthtbldetail[itd] );
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var lengthtbldetail = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
console.log(lengthtbldetail.length)
for (var itd = lengthtbldetail.length - 1; itd >= 0; itd--)
{
  if (lengthtbldetail[itd].innerHTML.indexOf('<td>') == -1) {
    lengthtbldetail[itd].parentNode.removeChild(lengthtbldetail[itd]);
  }
}
```

```html
<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />

<!--I want to Remove this table:-->
<table name="tbldetails">
</table>
<br />

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Demo with 30 tables**

```js
var lengthtbldetail = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
for (var itd = lengthtbldetail.length - 1; itd >= 0; itd--)
{
  if (lengthtbldetail[itd].innerHTML.indexOf('<td>') == -1) {
    lengthtbldetail[itd].parentNode.removeChild(lengthtbldetail[itd]);
  }
}
```

```html
<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />

<!--I want to Remove this table:-->
<table name="tbldetails">
</table>
<br />

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />

<!--I want to Remove this table:-->
<table name="tbldetails">
</table>
<br />

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />

<!--I want to Remove this table:-->
<table name="tbldetails">
</table>
<br />

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />

<!--I want to Remove this table:-->
<table name="tbldetails">
</table>
<br />

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />

<!--I want to Remove this table:-->
<table name="tbldetails">
</table>
<br />

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />

<!--I want to Remove this table:-->
<table name="tbldetails">
</table>
<br />

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />

<!--I want to Remove this table:-->
<table name="tbldetails">
</table>
<br />

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />

<!--I want to Remove this table:-->
<table name="tbldetails">
</table>
<br />

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />

<!--I want to Remove this table:-->
<table name="tbldetails">
</table>
<br />

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />

<!--I want to Remove this table:-->
<table name="tbldetails">
</table>
<br />

<table name="tbldetails">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Table 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to remove entire table with tag, I mean remove `<table name=...`

Comment: @Emma I have added a demo.

Comment: it work for one table, in my case, i have 3 to 20 table which has an empty row and td

Comment: @Emma empty `tr` and `td` is different from empty `table`. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: @Emma I have made change in the `for-loop`. It is now running in reverse. **Issue was** -  `lengthtbldetail`  a `Nodelist` is a live collection and if you remove items when you are iterating the same collection, length value changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158416/discussion-between-gurvinder372-and-emma).

Answer (score 0):

you can remove them by two ways.

> By native javascript:

```
var table = document.querySelectorAll('table:empty');
for (index = table.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    table[index].parentNode.removeChild(table[index]);
}
```

> By Jquery

```
$("table:empty").remove();
```